# SQL Server ChangeTracking suggest Delete while record is in the tracked table

Tags: sql-server, change-tracking

Im wondering what situation caused that I get the following result?

Performing `SELECT * FROM  CHANGETABLE(CHANGES dbo.FOO_TABLE, 697420)` is returning (for multiple records) SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION with symbol `D` -
Only with symbol `D` - there are no other SYS_CHANGES with `I` or `U`.

697420 is number greater than: `CHANGE_TRACKING_MIN_VALID_VERSION(OBJECT_ID('dbo.FOO_TABLE'))`

While performing `SELECT * FROM dbo.FOO_TABLE` returns those records.

Well, I know that there where updates done on that table, I expects to get there `U` SYS_CHANGES. Even when part of PRIMARY_KEY was updated I exects some `D` of old one and `I` of new one.

But `D` alone while record is still in the table is something I can't explain.

Im using SQL Server 2008 R2

Edit:
All possible changes on tracked table are done by merge:
There is temporary table `#TEMP_FOO_TABLE` created and filled with other part of system with the same columns as tracked `FOO_TABLE` plus one - OPERATION which is marker for what to be done:

```
    CREATE TABLE #TEMP_FOO_TABLE
        (
          OPERATION CHAR(1) NOT NULL ,
          FOO_TABLE_ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY ,
          SOME_FOREIGN_KEY_ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ,              
          SOME_COLUMN_A BIT ,
          SOME_COLUMN_B VARCHAR(50)
        );
```

Next we use Merge to perform insert/update operations:

```
MERGE dbo.FOO_TABLE AS TRG
    USING #TEMP_FOO_TABLE AS SRC
    ON TRG.FOO_TABLE_ID = SRC.FOO_TABLE_ID
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET AND SRC.OPERATION <> 'D' THEN
        INSERT ( FOO_TABLE_ID ,
                 SOME_FOREIGN_KEY_ID ,
                 SOME_COLUMN_A ,
                 SOME_COLUMN_B
               )
        VALUES ( FOO_TABLE_ID ,
                 SOME_FOREIGN_KEY_ID ,
                 SOME_COLUMN_A ,
                 SOME_COLUMN_B
               )
    WHEN MATCHED AND SRC.OPERATION = 'U' THEN
        UPDATE SET
                TRG.SOME_FOREIGN_KEY_ID = SRC.SOME_FOREIGN_KEY_ID ,
                TRG.SOME_COLUMN_A = SRC.SOME_COLUMN_A ,
                TRG.SOME_COLUMN_B = SRC.SOME_COLUMN_B;
```

Then for deletes: (it is separeted because related tables are merged meanwhile)

```
MERGE dbo.FOO_TABLE AS TRG
    USING #TEMP_FOO_TABLE AS SRC
    ON TRG.FOO_TABLE_ID = SRC.FOO_TABLE_ID
    WHEN MATCHED AND SRC.OPERATION = 'D' THEN
        DELETE;
```

Comment: If it's `D` that record was deleted. Simple as that. If you have a new record with an identical key value (eg because the key isn't generated by an `IDENTITY()`, you'll see both the deletion of the old value and the subsequent insertion. If you *don't* use SNAPSHOT isolation though but something very unfortunate, like `READ UNCOMMITTED` you may be seeing deletions that were eventually rolled back. That's why yoy shoudl always use a transaction at the SNAPSHOT isolation level.

Comment: BTW if the "updates" were performed by delete/insert operations instead of UPDATE, you won't see any `D`s.

Comment: In any case, you don't provide any information that can help further. You don't provide the statements you use to modify the table, the query you use to retrieve the modified records or even the table schema.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've added some code that shows how updates are performed. Also - u're right IDENTITY() isn't generated. Also SNAPSHOT isolation level is being used.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the product related to [split-sort-collapse](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/craigfr/2007/09/06/maintaining-unique-indexes/).

The contributing factor is related to updating any non-primary unique column with a non-constant value.  If the column that is part of unique constraint is updated with a value that is lesser than its current value, you would see this issue.

You can use the following workarounds to resolve this.

1.)    If feasible, get rid of the unique clustered index and replace that with clustered index.  This might have some performance implications.

2.)    Get rid of the clustered index and add those columns as part of primary key.

3.)    After the update on the merge statement, issue a dummy update on any other column.

> Update  set col-a = col-a where  = value

We have released a [fix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4135113/fix-change-tracking-record-is-inconsistent-during-an-update-on-a-table) for this for SQL 2016 SP1.  You could expect the fix for other versions in subsequent CUs.

Unfortunately, you will have upgrade to SQL 2014 at the minimum since SQL 2008 R2 is out of support through cumulative updates.